# Is $W^{k,p}$ a reflexive Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open bounded subset with smooth boundary. Is the Banach space $W^{k,p}(U)$ a reflexive Banach space? If not, for what $k$ and $p$ is it reflexive?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Sobolev spaces, just like the $L^p$ spaces, are reflexive when $1 < p < \infty$. To show this, note that $W^{k,p}(U)$ embeds as a Banach space inside a finite product of $L^p(U)$ spaces as
$$ u \mapsto (D^{\alpha}u)_{|\alpha| \leq k}. $$
A finite product of reflexive spaces is reflexive and a closed subspace of a reflexive space is reflexive and so $W^{k,p}(U)$ inherits it from the $L^p(U)$ spaces.

Comment: I see. The proof is easy after all. Thank you very much, levap!