# Proof that $\lVert u\rVert_{L^p(M)}\leq C\lVert\Delta u\rVert_{L^p(M)}$ for each $u\in W_0^{2,p}(M)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold with nontrivial boundary and $W_0^{2,p}(M)$ the elements of $W^{2,p}(M)$ that vanish on $\partial M$. I'm trying to understand a proof that there exists a constant $C$ such that
$$\lVert u\rVert_{L^p(M)}\leq C\lVert\Delta u\rVert_{L^p(M)}$$
for each $u\in W_0^{2,p}(M)$. Here is the proof:

> Suppose there does not exist such a constant. Then we can find a sequence $u_i$ with $\lVert u_i\rVert_{L^p}=1$ and $\Delta u_i\to 0$ in $L^p$. By the elliptic estimate
> $$\lVert u\rVert_{W^{k+2,p}}\ \leq K(\lVert Lu\rVert_{W^{k,p}}+\lVert u\rVert_{L^p})$$
> (existence of the constant $K$), it follows that $u_i$ is uniformly bounded in $W^{2,p}$. By the Rellich-Kondrachov compactness theorem, there exists a subsequence of $u_i$ converging to some function $u$ weakly in $W^{2,p}$ and strongly in $L^p$. Then for any compactly supported smooth test function $\psi$,
> $$\langle\Delta u,\psi\rangle=\langle u,\Delta\psi\rangle=\lim_{i\to\infty}\langle u_i,\Delta\psi\rangle=\lim_{i\to\infty}\langle\Delta u_i,\psi\rangle=0,$$
> and therefore $\Delta u=0$. By elliptic regularity, $u$ must be smooth. Since it vanishes on the boundary, the maximum principle implies that $u$ is identically zero. But this is a contradiction since we must have $\lVert u\rVert_{L^p}=1$.

I feel confused about many of its details:

1. The uniform boundedness here seems strange to me. In my introductory analysis course, a uniform bound is a constant $M$ such that $|u_i(x)|\leq M$ for every $x$ and for every $i$, but in the proof, it doesn't seem to work this way.
2. I have looked up the Rellich-Kondrachov compactness theorem in my PDE book and Wikipedia, and it doesn't refer to subsequences. How could the author grab such a subsequence?
3. Where does the equality $\langle\Delta u,\psi\rangle=\langle u,\Delta\psi\rangle$ come from? Is there an inner product on $L^p$? I only know $L^2$ can be equipped with an inner product, which makes it a Hilbert space.

Any suggestion is welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I don't know why, but many people say "uniformly bounded" when they really just mean "bounded". In this case it just means that there is a constant $M>0$ such that $\lVert u_i\rVert_{W^{2,p}}\leq M$ for all $i\in\mathbb N$.
2. The Rellich-Kondrachov compactness theorem tells you that the embedding $W^{2,p}(M)\hookrightarrow L^p(M)$ is compact. This means that bounded subsets of $W^{2,p}$ are compact in $L^p(M)$, and a subset of a metric space is compact if and only if every sequence has a convergent subsequence. That gives you strong convergence in $L^p(M)$. To additionally get weak convergence in $W^{2,p}(M)$, note that $W^{2,p}(M)$ is separable and [reflexive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259641/is-wk-p-a-reflexiv-banach-space) (this holds only if $1<p<\infty$). Then we know from the Banach-Alaoglu theorem that every bounded sequence in $W^{2,p}(M)$ has a weakly convergent subsequence in $W^{2,p}(M)$.
3. The symbol $\langle\cdot\,,\cdot\rangle$ does not denote an inner product here, but a dual pairing between say $L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}(M)$ and $C_c^\infty(M)$. In other words,
   $$
   \langle v,\phi\rangle=\int v(x) \phi(x)\,dx.
   $$
   The identity $\langle \Delta u,\psi\rangle=\langle u,\Delta \psi\rangle$ is just the definition of the distributional Laplacian.

Comment: Pardon me for asking lower questions. According to Evans' PDE book, I only have $W^{1,p}\subset\subset L^q$ for $1\leq q<p^*$, that is, $W^{1,p}$ is compactly embedded in $L^q$ for $1\leq q<p^*$. How do I get rid of the messy indices $q$ and $p^*$ to obtain the compact embedding $W^{2,p}(M)\hookrightarrow L^p(M)$ you mentioned?

Comment: It is true that this is not very obvious from this version of the theorem. But the embedding $W^{1,p}(M)\hookrightarrow L^p(M)$ is always compact for compact $M$. For domains this is Theorem 9.16 in Brezis. *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations*, and is usually also called Rellich-Kondrachov embedding theorem.

Comment: The author only defined the $g$-Laplacian $f\mapsto\Delta f=\mathrm{div}(\nabla f)$. Is there any difference between his definition and the distributional Laplacian you mentioned? Thank you.

Comment: @Steve For your definition you still need to say what $\nabla$ and $\mathrm{div}$ are if the function is not classically differentiable. But in the end, all reasonable definitions should amount to the same quantity.

Comment: In the proof, the author guarantees that a subsequence of $u_i$ converges to some function $u$ weakly in $W^{2,p}$ and strongly in $L^p$. What is this subsequence for? The $u_i$'s in $\lim_{i\to\infty}\langle u_i,\Delta\psi\rangle$ is the orginal sequence, not a subsequence. Could you tell me its whereabouts? Thank you.

Comment: No, they should be the subsequence, it's just not properly written.

Comment: I'm sorry to constantly bother you. Let's pretend that $\{u_i\}$ denotes the subsequence in question. How do we know that $$\lim_{i\to\infty}\int u_i\Delta\psi=\int u\Delta\psi?\tag{$*$}$$ Without doubt, $u_i\to u$ strongly in $L^p$, which implies $u_i\to u$ weakly in $L^p$. Then, if we had $\Delta\psi\in L^q$, we would conclude ($*$). Here $q$ is conjugate to $p$. However, all I know is that $\Delta\psi$ lies in $L^1$ since it is a continuous function. This is far from the desire. Could you give me a piece of advice? Thank you. 感激不盡。

Comment: Since $\psi$ is compactly supported and smooth, so is $\Delta\psi$, which implies $\Delta\psi\in L^q$ for *all* $q\in[1,\infty]$.

Comment: In the latter part of your reply, did you employ the fact that if $q_1<q_2$, then $L^{q_2}\subset L^{q_1}$? Does it really make $q$ able to roam through $[1,\infty]$? Thank you.

Comment: The point is that $\Delta\psi$ is bounded and compactly supported. Therefore you have $\int|\Delta\psi(x)|^p\,dx\leq \|\Delta\psi\|_\infty^p \cdot\textrm{measure}(\mathrm{supp\,}\psi)$, which is finite.

Comment: Finally, I made out what you meant. Thanks a lot. There is now another question: how do we see from the maximum principle that $u$ is identically zero? Is $u$ a non-negative function or something? If so, then that $u$ vanishes on $\partial M$ would guarantee its being zero everywhere.

Comment: You can apply the maximum principle to $u$ and $-u$. Both must have maximum zero (since it's attained on the bounday), hence $u=0$.

Comment: Thank you for everything.